# PHP usort Understanding

Tags: php, usort

```
function cmp_function($a, $b)

{

if ($a == $b) return 0;
  return ($a > $b) ? -1 : 1;

}

$fruits = array("d"=>"lemon", "a"=>"orange", "b"=>"banana" );

usort($fruits, "cmp_function");
```

Question: What values will be passed for $a and $b parameters for `cmp_fucntion()`?

Comment: "If everything else fails, read the f* manual".

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski To be fair, that isn't explained in the manual.

Comment: @khanz This [comment in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php#108116) may help.

Comment: You could always write a little bit of test code and find out for yourself :) http://3v4l.org/YoG81

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$a` will be first element of two compared at this point, while `$b` will be second compared element at this point of sorting algorithm.

E.g.:

```
 iteration |     $a   |    $b
 -------------------------------
      1      "lemon"  |   "orange"
      2      "orange" |   "banana"
      3      "banana" |   "lemon"
           ...
```